# Is there a way to include subfolders in a SPListCollection dropdown?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, document-library, dropdown

I'm trying to include subfolders of document libraries in a dropdown list, already have the document libraries working, but not the subfolders. Here's my code:

```
SPListCollection spLists = spWeb.Lists;
        spLists.IncludeRootFolder = true;
        int iIndex = 0;
        bool bDocLibAvailable = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < spLists.Count; i++)
        {
            SPList spList = spLists[i];
            if ((!spList.Hidden) && (spList.BaseType == SPBaseType.DocumentLibrary) && (spList.BaseTemplate == SPListTemplateType.DocumentLibrary))
            {
                bool bHasPermission = false;
                bool oldState = spServer.CatchAccessDeniedException;
                try
                {
                    spServer.CatchAccessDeniedException = false;
                    bHasPermission = spList.Permissions.DoesUserHavePermissions(SPRights.AddListItems);
                }
                catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
                {
                }
                finally
                {
                    spServer.CatchAccessDeniedException = oldState;
                }
                if (bHasPermission)
                {
                    bDocLibAvailable = true;            
                    string value = SPEncode.HtmlEncode(spList.ID.ToString("B").ToUpper());
                    // ListItem encodes the text already, so no HTML encode here is needed
                    string text = spList.Title;
                    ListItem li = new ListItem(text, value);
                    if(iIndex == 0)
                    {
                        li.Selected = true;
                    }
                    onetidDocLibIDSelect.Items.Add(li);
                    iIndex++;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop through folders once you are inside a list:

```
foreach (SPFolder folder in list.Folders)
{

}
```